# Pandas automatically converts row to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, shapes

I have a very simple dataframe like so:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   A  B  C
0  2  a  a
1  3  s  3
2  4  c  !
3  1  f  1
```

My goal is to extract the first row in such a way that looks like this:

```
   A  B  C
0  2  a  a
```

As you can see the dataframe shape (1x3) is preserved and the first row still has 3 columns.

However when I type the following command `df.loc[0]` the output result is this:

```
df.loc[0]
Out[9]: 
A    2
B    a
C    a
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

As you can see the row has turned into a column with 3 rows! (3x1 instead of 3x1). How is this possible? how can I simply extract the row and preserve its shape as described in my goal? Could you provide a smart and elegant way to do it?

I tried to use the transpose command `.T` but without success... I know I could create another dataframe where the columns are extracted by the original dataframe but this way quite tedious and not elegant I would say (`pd.DataFrame({'A':[2], 'B':'a', 'C':'a'})`).

Here is the dataframe if you need it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,4,1], 'B':['a','s','c','f'], 'C':['a', 3, '!', 1]})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need add `[]` for `DataFrame`:

```
#select by index value
print (df.loc[[0]])
   A  B  C
0  2  a  a
```

Or:

```
print (df.iloc[[0]])
   A  B  C
0  2  a  a
```

If need transpose `Series`, first need convert it to `DataFrame` by [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
print (df.loc[0].to_frame())
   0
A  2
B  a
C  a

print (df.loc[0].to_frame().T)
   A  B  C
0  2  a  a
```

Comment: Ok I see this is the best way... however I still wander why .T does not work... is this a bug?

Comment: No, but need first convert to `DataFrame` by `to_frame`, then is possible transpose, because `Series` cannot be transpose

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Comment: Also, by using `df.loc[[0]]` you are preserving the potentially varying dtypes across columns.  `df.loc[0]` automatically converts the row to a series and converts potentially different dtypes to a common dtype.

Answer (score 2):

Use a range selector will preserve the Dataframe format.

```
df.iloc[0:1]
Out[221]: 
   A  B  C
0  2  a  a
```